# External NMEA GPS to Apple's CLLocation manager

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gps, nmea

If I would have a (custom made) external BT LE gps receiver (receiving NMEA GPS signals) that I would connect with bluetooth to an iOS device, would this automatically work with the CLLocation Manager services in all my Apps?

The BT LE connection is custom made hardware, is there any info of how to configure this to act like a iOS supported (MFi) GPS receiver?

Any tips or pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for your own custom made GPS to get integrated
with CLLocationManager unless you become a MFi vendor.

However, if you are targeting Jailbroken device, it's technically possible.
This is because [BTStackGPS](http://www.ringwald.ch/cydia/gps/) is integrated with the system so that we can use Apple's map application with non-MFi external NMEA bluetooth GPS. BTStack is [open source](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack) and it's said that BTStackGPS runs on the BTStack. It supports BLE, too. Note BTStackGPS is not open source, so you need your own research on how to integrate your SW with the system.