# react-native - get GPS NMEA info

Tags: android, ios, react-native, gps

I am researching about getting GPS info for react native apps. Currently, I am getting stuck at the GPS NMEA.

Below are some useful links I found for the Android OS:

- [Android NMEA GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562516/android-nmea-gps)
- [Source of NMEA sentences in Android LocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436361/source-of-nmea-sentences-in-android-locationmanager)
- [GpsStatus.NmeaListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener)
- [OnNmeaMessageListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/OnNmeaMessageListener)

For iOS, I also found some useful links, but the path still not clear enough:

- [External NMEA GPS to Apple's CLLocation manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209987/external-nmea-gps-to-apples-cllocation-manager)

After doing research, I wonder if there is any way that we can get the NMEA from Apple iPhone or iPad without jailbreak?

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to provide NMEA data to the iOS device from an external GPS receiver (that is what the question you linked is asking) or do you want to get NMEA data from the iOS device GPS. If so, that is not possible.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thank you for the comment. Actually, I want to get NMEA data from the iOS device GPS. Do you have an official page said that we can't do it? Because I have to write a report after researching. Many thanks!

Comment: Read the Core Location framework documentation - that describes how apps get access to location on iOS.  There is no access to NMEA data. There is no official page that lists the things you *can't* do.  There are an infinite number of things you *can't* do.  Why do you want NMEA data?  You could take the location data that iOS provides and use that to generate NMEA data strings.

Comment: @Paulw11: hi there, I found that NMEA may contain nearly everything I need for the location info. That's why I am kinda curious if there is anyway we can get the NMEA then extract the information from it. However, it looks like now I am curious again to generate the NMEA from GPS info, haha.

Comment: You will get a series of [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation) objects - You should be able to create most NMEA data from them - It includes location, altitude, accuracy, speed and course

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks mate, just Google it but still can't find the algorithm for it.

Comment: What algorithm?  You would just construct strings from the location objects. I still don't understand why you would want NMEA data. That's an ascii format that makes it easy for gps units to talk to chart plotters on ships. You would have to parse the NMEA sentences to use the data anyway

Comment: @Paulw11: Oh, I see, thank you for the information